# Push to Mute Mic for an Individual Program in Windows 10

Tags: audio, programming, windows-10

Is there a way to mute my mic (push to mute) for a single windows 10 application (xbox app) while keeping it active for all other applications?

I'm a twitch streamer and would like to mute my stream banter to my friends.

Comment: Pretty sure you can do this in Windows audio settings, and you can control volume for individual applications.

Answer (score 1):

OBS has some push to mute options as do some games,  however if your friends are open to discord I would look at setting up a room in a discord server for you as a twitch streamer that you can move your friends in when streaming,  them discord has either push to talk or push to mute options,  you could configure OBS Pute to Talk and Discord Push to mute to be the same key as an example,  I am working on figuring it out myself to xxkaylethxx on twitch.